# iOS Animate Translation of a rotated view

Tags: ios, animation, transform

I have a view that is slanted as in rotated by an angle. To rotate I used CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. Now I want to animate it going up vertically or in other words in negative y axis relative to the root view for 100 px. But my view needs to know X and Y components of that 100 px in terms of its own X and Y system. I use trigonometry to find those values and its works fine but the problem is that when I animate it using CGAffineTransformTranslate , it moves the view in the X direction first (non animated, jumps) then in Y (animated). How can I make it translate properly in both dimensions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame

> The value in the center property is always valid, even if scaling or
>   rotation factors have been added to the view’s transform. The same is
>   not true for the value in the frame property, which is considered
>   invalid if the view’s transform is not equal to the identity
>   transform.

So when you applies `non identity transform` like `rotation` the frames becomes invalid. You should not use frame for transformed view. Instead you can use `center` property for repositioning view.

Comment: oh my god thanks so much. That saved me some headache pills for sure.